# Why Broomhilda rather than Brunhilda?

Tags: django-unchained

Why is [Django's wife](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0316650/)'s name spelt *Broomhilda* rather than *Brunhilda* (or *Broonhilda*)? I have only come across the latter spelling (and variants such as *Brunhilde*, *Brünnhilde* or *Brynhilde*) in the mythological story. I didn't actually notice that Django was pronouncing his wife's name with an *M*. But I do seem to distinctly remember Dr. Schultz pronouncing her name (in his German accent) more like *Brünnhilde*.

I see that there's a 1970s newspaper comic strip named [Broom-Hilda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broom-Hilda) where the titular character is a witch. The name is therefore a pun on *Brunhilda*.

[image: Broom-Hilda]

So, what gives? Is Tarantino tipping his hat towards the comic? If not, is he suggesting that the German plantation owners spelt her name so? Do the characters in the movie pronounce her name with an *M*? I don't remember if there's a shot where her name is displayed—perhaps in Greenville, or when the contracts are signed in Candieland.

(I don't believe that it is suggested anywhere that Broomhilda was also taught how to read and write by her mistress. Django only learns to do so midway through the film.)

Comment: I just finished reading the Vertigo comic adaptation, (which, BTW, was excellent,) and the name is in print countless times, spoken by Schultz (even as he is relating the legend of Brunhilde to Django), spoken by Django, spoken by EVERYone, and never is it spelled any way other than Broomhilda, with no explanation. It made me curious enough to consult the Great Google, who led me to this thread. I can only conclude that it was a complete oversight by Quentin, he simply didn't know any better (and, evidently, neither did any of his editors or proof-readers or whomever is supposed to prevent the

Answer (score 8):

First of all, she is indeed spelled *Broomhilda* (with an *"M"*) both in the credits and throughout the movie. I think it's only *Schultz* who calls her *Brunhilda* due to his habits. I just understood that as a parody of the original name, emphasizing her status as a slave, since she's supposed to carry a *broom* when cleaning up behind her masters, something along those lines.

I just thought it has always been her name. But given that her original plantation owners were Germans it may also be that her original name was indeed *Brunhilda* and the parody name was only developed later by other plantation owners, overseers, or co-slaves.

But it might also have another meaning, given that comic-strip and *Tarantino*'s fondness for the 70s.

Comment: It might also have been a mis-heard word taking on a life of its own, like Amsterdam becoming "Hamsterdam" in "The Wire".

Answer (score 3):

Note that the proper spelling is Brünnhilde, so "broom" is not the only change, also the -e to an -a. Tarantino pretty obviously took the spelling from the comic strip, but I see no symbolism there other than the obvious: humiliation of a slave woman who inside was a proud valkyrie, and mocking Southern whites ignorant of the Nibelungenlied, their cultural heritage (Wagner's opera was first performed in 1869, so they would not have known about that). Tarantino mocked the whites' pretensions and facade in other ways, like how Calvin Candie favored French but didn't speak it himself (despite plenty of money and leisure time to learn it).

Comment: Yet the version of the *Nibelungenlied* told by *Schultz* in the movie wasn't really that accurate as well and was much more archaic and more similar to the Nordic *Sigurd*-legend on which the more modern and medieval *Nibelungenlied* was likely based on. So in fact this ignorance of the *Nibelungelied* could also be blamed on *Schultz*, too (or maybe *Tarantino*?).

Answer (score 1):

I think the movie purposely makes many allusions to mid and late 20th century popular culture as well.  Broomhilda is not the only character named after a comic strip. Leonardo Di Caprio's character is named Calvin (Calvin and Hobbs) he lives on the Candie-Land (similar to the children's board game) ranch. Django and Broomhilda are supposed to be the ancestors of Shaft according to IMDB.  The name Django itself was taken from the hero of a string of spaghetti westerns, which in turn took the name from the famous Gypsy Jazz guitar legend, Django Reinhardt. I'm sure there are many other references as well.

Comment: Sure there aren't other famous people called *Calvin* or other famous places called *Candyland* (apart from a board game)? Nobody argues that *Tarantino* scatters references to anything everywhere, but those in particular seem too far-fetched and unrelated when provided without any proofs. And besides that I cannot see in which way this answers the actual question at all.